# Javascript search for words that are not in sequence

Tags: javascript, search

I'm a novice when it comes to Javascript.

I would like to improve the search in the script provided below.

I have the following code and currently when I type the phrase 'blue widgets' in search, it will only identify/find the checkbox if the phrase 'blue widgets' exits in sequence. For example, If I have a keyword phrase or sentence that contains 'blue cool widgets' and I search for 'blue widgets' it is unable to locate that even though blue and widgets both exist in my keyword phrase.

Could it be possible that if I search for a phrase with 2 or even 3 words in it, then it can find any keyword phrase/sentence on my page in which all words of my search phrase exist and then check the box (which the code already does). The only condition is that all the words of my search phrase have to exist in a sentence/string ?

I would very much appreciate if this solution can be found.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForWord( wordField )
{
var form = wordField.form;
var word = wordField.value.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"").toLowerCase();

var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
for ( var e = 0; e < inputs.length; ++e )
{
    var field = inputs[e];
    if ( field.type == "checkbox" )
    {
        if ( field.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0 )
        {
            field.checked = true;
        } else {
            // OPTIONAL, if you do NOTwant to clear previously checked boxes, omit next              line:
            field.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
Type a word: <input name="word" onchange="checkForWord(this);" />
<hr>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="This is an example sentence with blue and     cool widgets not in order and my current script will not find it.
</label></br/>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="This sentence will be found if I search for blue widgets because its in this sentence">
All work and no play makes Jack
</label></br/>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="I would like for it to be able to find this sentence also since blue and widgets both words exist but are out of order. 
</label></br/>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be the best to tokenize your search string (split it by words), execute each search independently (for every word) and then merge results.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?=.*blue)(?=.*widgets)/.test( phrase );
```

`(?=...)` is a look-ahead, meaning it only matches if the expression is matched somewhere further in the string.  The nice part is that it doesn't *consume* the match, so the above will only match if you have "blue" and "widgets" at some point later in the string, but order doesn't matter.

Feel free to modify those to wrap with whitespace if necessary so that it only matches the entire word (e.g. wrap the words with `\b`)

To generate that regex dynamically:

```
var words = 'blue widgets';
new RegExp( '(?=.*' + words.split( /\W+/g ).join( ')(?=.*' ) + ')', 'i' )
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the above code is not mine but someone helped me out with that. I'm very much a novice, so can you please tell me where that RegExp code would fit in the existing code?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to implement your suggestion. Can you please modify my code as per your suggestion. I'm very new to javascript. Thanks for your assistance.